# Paste copied lists at the very end of a row

Tags: vba, excel

At the moment I’m only able to copy&paste stuff from one row.

I use the code below:

```
        Dim lastRow As Long

    With Sheets("Tab1")
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(3)) <> 0 Then
            lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Else
            lastRow = 1
        End If

        Sheets("Tabelle2").Range("B85:S85").copy

        .Range("C" & lastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    End With
```

My problem is that I need to copy and paste lists.  Can someone show me how to use this code to copy&paste lists?

> I wanted to copy more rows, like `(A25:S25, A27:S27, A30:S30)`
>
> It should copy always the same rows.

Comment: Do you mean if i need the text without formating..?
ATM i only need the numbers but later on i want to copy it with format... so yes and no?

Comment: To get a list, I assume it's in some range? Just change the range in `Sheets("Tabelle2").Range("B85:S85").Copy`, the `B85:S85` is the range being copied. Change that to match your list range.

Comment: nope that is not working.. i tried that before..

Comment: If you change the range, and try the macro - what do you mean by it doesn't work? The new range doesn't copy? It isn't the range you expected? It doesn't paste properly, etc?

Comment: pastespecial isn't able to copy more than one row.... how can i close the question?

Comment: This is not correct **pastespecial isn't able to copy more than one row** see my answer...

Comment: I tried to expend the range but the code stopped working and @siddhard rout told me its not possible with paste special..

Comment: have you tried my code? could you answer the two key questions 1) what's the range you need to copy it's just "B85:S85" 2) To how many rows do you need to copy it? then adapt the code I provided. If you tell me both answers I can show how to do it. It's in the answer...

Comment: "pastespecial isn't able to copy more than one row.... " correct, but that's just because `pasteSpecial` is to, well, paste.  How would it copy a row?  You can **copy** more than one row all day long.

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons for your code copying just one row:

1. The code selects just one row to copy

   ```
   Sheets("Tabelle2").Range("B85:S85").Copy
   ```
2. The select just on row to Paste

   ```
   .Range("C" & lastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues …
   ```

As it’s not clear if you want to copy several rows despite selecting just one or to copy that one row to several rows I’ll cover both options in order to give you an idea of what to do in both cases:

1. Setting the range to be copied

   a. To copy just range `B85:S85` one row only then what you are doing is correct

   ```
   Wbk.Sheets("Tabelle2").Range("B85:S85")
   ```

   b. To copy X rows down from row 85 (including row 85)

   ```
   Wbk.Sheets("Tabelle2").Range("B85:S85").Resize(X)
   ```

   c. To copy Y rows up from row 85 (including row 85)

   ```
   Wbk.Sheets("Tabelle2").Range("B85:S85").Offset(1-Y, 0).Resize(Y)
   ```

   d. To copy the range bounded by any combination of blank rows and blank columns in which "B85:S85" is included (see [Range.CurrentRegion Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff196678.aspx))

   ```
   Wbk.Sheets("Tabelle2").Range("B85:S85").CurrentRegion
   ```

   *Note that this will include also any rows above and below row `85` if they have at least one cell not blank that causes the "current region" to extend upwards or downwards and it will also include any columns to the left of columns `B` or to the right of column `S` if they have at least one cell not blank that causes the "current region" to extend sideways*

This procedure demonstrates the options explained above:

```
Sub Range_Set()
Dim rSrc As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle2")

        'If want to copy just this row 85
        Application.Goto .Cells(1), 1
        Set rSrc = .Range("B85:S85")
        rSrc.Select: Stop

        'If want to copy 5 rows down from row 85 (including row 85)
        Application.Goto .Cells(1), 1
        Set rSrc = .Range("B85:S85").Resize(5)
        rSrc.Select: Stop

        'If want to copy 5 rows up from row 85 (including row 85)
        Application.Goto .Cells(1), 1
        Set rSrc = .Range("B85:S85").Offset(-4, 0).Resize(5)
        rSrc.Select: Stop

        'If want to copy then range bounded by any combination of blank rows and blank columns in which "B85:S85" is included
        'This will include also any rows above and below row 85 if they have at least one cell not blank that causes the "current region" to extend upwards or downwards
        'Also will include also any columns to the left of columns B or to the right of column S if they have at least one cell not blank that causes the "current region" to extend sideways
        Application.Goto .Cells(1), 1
        Set rSrc = .Range("B85:S85").CurrentRegion
        rSrc.Select: Stop

    End With

End Sub
```

2. Setting the range where the copy takes place

To copy the source range as it is, then just need to select the first cell of your target range and the `paste.special` will cover paste the target to all cells required as per the size all target cell. However is you want to copy range `B85:S85’ to several cell then you need to select the target rows. For example if we want to copy`B85:S85’ over five rows starting at `C5` then we need to set the target range as

```
    .Range("C12").Resize(5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

As we are going to copy only the values of the source, I suggest to use the `Range.Value` property of the Range object instead of the `Copy…Paste` method. One advantage of using this property is to avoid the use of the Clipboard.

Try this code *(select\adjust the options as per your requirements)*

```
Sub Range_Value()
Dim Wbk As Workbook
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim rSrc As Range

    Rem Declare Objects
    Set Wbk = ThisWorkbook          'use this if procedure is resident in the wbk with the tables
    'Set Wbk = Workbooks(WbkName)    'use this if procedure is not resident in the wbk with the tables - update wbk name

    With Wbk.Sheets("Tab1")

        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        Rem Set Copy Range
        'since we are going to paste only values then we can save us from using the clippboard
        'Sheets("Tabelle2").Range("B85:S85").Copy
        'instaed create a range to replace the values of the target range with the values of this range

        'Uncomment\Update the option needed according to you requirements
        'for this test I'm using option b

        'a. To copy just row 85
        'Set rSrc = Wbk.Sheets("Tabelle2").Range("B85:S85")

        'b. To copy X rows down from row 85 (including row 85) X=5
        Set rSrc = Wbk.Sheets("Tabelle2").Range("B85:S85").Resize(5)

        'c. To copy 5 rows up from row 85 (including row 85) Y=5
        'Set rSrc = Wbk.Sheets("Tabelle2").Range("B85:S85").Offset(-4, 0).Resize(5)

        'd. To copy the range bounded by any combination of blank rows and blank columns in which "B85:S85" is included
        'This will include also any rows above and below row 85 if they have at least one cell not blank that causes the "current region" to extend upwards or downwards
        'Also will include also any columns to the left of columns B or to the right of column S if they have at least one cell not blank that causes the "current region" to extend sideways
        'Set rSrc = Wbk.Sheets("Tabelle2").Range("B85:S85").CurrentRegion

        ' As mentioned before we won't use the clipboard
        'instead we replace the values with the values of the target range created earlier
        'however we need to extend the range to the same size of the source range
        .Range("C" & lastRow + 1).Resize(rSrc.Rows.Count, rSrc.Columns.Count).Value = rSrc.Value2

    End With

End Sub
```

Hope this is clear enough and helps you to make progress with you coding, nevertheless let me know of any questions you might have.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understud what i wanted to do or if my english is too weak that i don't understand what you mean.
I wanted to copy more rows, like that (A25:S25, A27:S27, A30:S30)

I'm not sure if your code is able to do that..

Comment: Wow, that's a great explanation and breakdown - kudos!!  @Swi - if this doesn't help, take some time to read it and extrapolate a little.  I think your question is not about copying, but rather how to loop? Please explain a little better (in your OP).

Comment: Ok the rows you want to copy are not in a continuous range? So how do you determine them or it's a hard coded range?

Comment: It should copy always the same rows. 

ATM I solved the problem with a friend of mine... but i would love to see if your code works, i think you code is not so akward like mine
greets (i'm posting my code as an answer)

Comment: "It should always copy the same rows." does **not** jive with "I wanted to copy more rows, like that (A25:S25, A27:S27...)".  Next time please think through your question and ask it in a more clear manner.  What do you want to do?? Have you read through @EEM's code? It should be more than enough info. for what you're looking for.

Comment: @Swi  You must understand that is not about us not understanding but certainly about you making an effort to clearly communicate what your issue is. Help yourself by helping us to help you...

Comment: It is always copying the same rows! like that (A25:S25, A27:S27...)

Comment: Ok now that you have clarified things, I can certainly tell you that it's possible to achieve. It's just a matter of perspective. I'll provide a second answer

Comment: One more thing it's only? (A25:S25, A27:S27, A30:S30)  tell me all the ranges... Also we are still pasting values only?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're looking for - but here' how to loop:

```
Sub test()
For i = 25 to 30
    Range(Cells(i,1),Cells(i,19)).Copy
    Range(Cells(i,20),Cells(i,39)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Next i
End Sub
```

That copies A25:S25 and pastes to T25:AM25...Then A26:S26, pastes T26:AM26, etc. until row 31.

Answer (score 0):

Well now that the requirements are disclosed, we have the opportunity to apply another method. Bear in mind that the fact that the source range contains multiple areas may give us the idea of series of repetitive "copy paste values" which makes the undesirable use of the clipboard, or a repetitive Range Values.

This time instead of setting the source range as an object (which still can be done) we'll use an Array variable to grab the values of the multi-areas range
to later enter them in the target range as a unified and continuous range in one step.

This procedure sets an array with the values of the source range areas and then sets the values of the array to the target range using the Range.Value property.

```
Sub Range_MultiAreas_CopyValue()
Const kRowIni As Long = 25
Dim Wbk As Workbook
Dim aRngSrc() As Variant
Dim lRowLst As Long, l As Long, b As Byte

    Rem Declare Objects
    Set Wbk = ThisWorkbook

    Rem Set Array with rows to copy as value
    With Wbk.Sheets("Tabelle2")
        l = kRowIni
        For b = 1 To 30
            If .Range("V" & l).Value2 = 0 Then
                Rem Resize Array
                On Error Resume Next
                ReDim Preserve aRngSrc(1 + UBound(aRngSrc))
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then ReDim Preserve aRngSrc(1)
                On Error GoTo 0
                Rem Set Row Values In Array
                aRngSrc(UBound(aRngSrc)) = .Cells(l, 2).Resize(, 16).Value2
                Rem Increase Row Pointer
                l = l + 2
    End If: Next: End With

    Rem Reset Arrays Structure
    With WorksheetFunction
        aRngSrc = .Transpose(.Transpose(aRngSrc))
    End With

    Rem Let Array Values in Target Range
    With Wbk.Sheets("Tab1")
        lRowLst = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lRowLst = IIf(.Cells(1, 1) = Empty, 1, lRowLst + 1)
        .Cells(lRowLst, 1).Resize(UBound(aRngSrc, 1), UBound(aRngSrc, 2)).Value = aRngSrc
    End With

End Sub
```

Once again let me know of any question you might have about the resources used.

Answer (score -1):

As it is not possible to Copy more than one row at once when gaps are between as siddharth rout said we tried to bypass the problem with looping through every signle row which should be copiedand added an if query. 
This code is working and i am using "him" now

```
        j = 0

    For i = 1 To 30

        With Sheets("Arbeiter-Tage")
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(1)) <> 0 Then
                lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Else
                lastRow = 1
            End If

            Sheets("Vorlage").Activate

            If ActiveSheet.Range("V" & 25 + j).Value = 0 Then

                ActiveSheet.Range("B" & 25 + j & ":" & "Q" & 25 + j).Copy

                .Range("A" & lastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            End If

        End With

    j = j + 2
```

Comment: "As it is not possible to copy more than one row at once when gaps are between..." is incorrect, why do you say that?  Is this a solution you're posting? More info?